# Solving simultaneous trigonometric equations

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**Question:** Solve the following equations for $x$ and $y$ $$\sin(y)= \sin(x-y)$$
$$\cos(x)= \sin(x-y)$$

where $x,y\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

**My attempt:**

The beginning of the solution seems to have something to do with $${\rm (i)} \quad y={\pi\over2}+x\qquad\vee\qquad{\rm   (ii)} \quad y={\pi\over2}-x$$

However I cannot understand how this conclusion was made.

Comment: You obviously have $\sin y=\cos x$

Comment: Can I just check that your equation (2) is $\cos(x)=\cos(x-y)$ and **not** what is printed above?

Comment: Well, this immediately means $\sin(y)=cos(x)$. Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: I just can't get my head around it, yes I have concluded that $\sin(y)=\cos(x)$, but surely that would mean $x=y=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: No, my equation (2) is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use trigonometric complementary angle formula

$$\sin(y)=\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$$

Comment: I don't understand where you have got the second equality from

Comment: This is the complementary angle formula. Just draw a unit circle and see that the $\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)$

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without the use of this formula?

Comment: Am I correct in saying the correct answer is $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: Good question ... I don't know another way of doing this atm. But this formula is a very basic one and nothing fancy. I will think about a way to show this without using this formula, but I doubt, that there is another way which is even simpler than the use of this formula.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help!